# zsh alternative to bash's declare -n

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a script in `bash` which uses `declare -n` inside a function to get a reference to a variable received as a parameter. Now I want this function to work also in `zsh`.

¿Is there an alternative to `declare -n` in `zsh`?

---

Here is my code:

```
f() {
    declare -n inside=$1
    inside="inside function"
}
a="outside function"
f a
echo "$a"
```

In `bash` it prints:

> inside function

In `zsh`:

> f:1: bad option: -n

Comment: You can use `typeset` over `declare` as it is POSIX recommended and `declare` is a `bash` only syntax.

Comment: With `typeset` I still get the error: `f:1: bad option: -n`

Comment: You don't need the `-n` option in `zsh` shell, http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html

Comment: `declare -n` is relatively new in Bash as well.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 discusses alternatives and also shows how to do this in `zsh`.

Comment: Without the `-n` option, it prints `outside function` which is not what I expect.

Comment: The common solution for pointer variables in zsh is to use the syntax `${(P)var}` which is not portable as well. I do not know of a portable solution except eval.

Comment: Something like `# Bash/ksh93/zsh; eval "$(printf %s=%q "$ref" "$value")"`. Please [read FAQ 006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: @sorontar The `${(P)var}` is suitable for indirection, but I don't get a reference to the variable, so I can not modify the outer variable (`a`). Thanks for the link, I will take a look at it.

Comment: Yes, you do get a "name" of the var to change in the function f. Make: `: ${(P)1::="new value"}` (do not remove the colon) as the unique content of the function to make it work (only) in zsh.

Comment: @Inian `-n` isn't part of POSIX, so it doesn't really matter that `declare` isn't part of POSIX either.